# How can I change a color in a material ui sticky header table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Without *stickyHeader* I can change its color, but when I put *stickyHeader* the color becomes its default as white.

```
<Table aria-label="customized table" >
<TableHead stickyHeader style={{backgroundColor: "black"  }}>
```

Comment: <Table aria-label="customized table" >
<TableHead stickyHeader style={{backgroundColor: "black"  }}>

Comment: Try to give style to `TableCell` elements. You can see here [Solution Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-szz46?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you actually have a row with at least one cell. Otherwise the `TableHead` has nothing to render

```
// ...
<TableHead stickyHeader style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
  <TableRow>
    <TableCell>Cell Content</TableCell>
    // More cells...
  </TableRow>
</TableHead>
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As shubham Baranwall said,specify the backgroundColor style at not  but  as follows,

```
<TableHead stickyHeader={true} >
    <TableCell style={{backgroundColor: "black"}}> HeadColumn1 <TableCell> 
    <TableCell style={{backgroundColor: "black"}}> HeadColumn2 <TableCell> 
    <TableCell style={{backgroundColor: "black"}}> HeadColumn3 <TableCell> 
</TableHead>
```